# canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"

Tags: xcode, facebook, parse-platform, swift2, ios9

Must say this error is driving me nuts and I am at my wits end. I would like to say that I've read through tons of articles on how to fix this error, I've implemented the solutions given, and this error is still here.

Here is some information on what I am using

Facebook iOS sdk v4.7.1
Parse iOS sdk 1.9.1
Xcode Version 7.1.1
Swift 2.1

I have seen all sorts of solutions regarding the plist, i have updated my plist many times over with, to my knowledge, the proper credentials. Here is my entire plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.9.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb1679166828968529</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.9.1</string>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>1679166828968529</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>Student Kitchen</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>akamaihd.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>facebook.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>fbcdn.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have the proper skds for both Facebook and Parse imported into my project. In both my AppDelegate.swift file and the Viewcontroller.swift file i have imported the following at the top.

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseFacebookUtilsV4
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
```

I have turned bitcode off. I have done everything i've read and this error still persists. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I also would like to note that i am aware Facebook says this is an error that can be ignored. However this does not apply in my case. I am trying to launch the Facebook login screen to log into my app with, and the simulator starts up and goes to a white screen immediately, it does not switch to the Facebook login because of this error which is why i can't ignore it. I also can not try to run the app on my phone as it is an iPhone 4 and is running iOS 7 and i am trying to ensure this works for iOS 9. Also downgrading versions in either Facebook or parse sdks is not an option.

I have also reset the content and settings of the simulator multiple times.

Thank you in advance to whoever can help, i have seen many people with the same error but no proper solution, and I am sure they will all be grateful as will I.

Comment: Can you provide your implantation information for login?